# Do I need more than 1 Antenna / Comms / Communotron?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

What might the reason for taking more than 1 Antenna into orbit / space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little searching I found an update to this question. Please refer to [*Antenna / Range table (Commnet)*](https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalSpaceProgram/comments/559z1e/antenna_range_table_commnet/) by [Toukiedatak](https://www.reddit.com/u/Toukiedatak) at [/r/KerbalSpaceProgram](https://www.reddit.com/r/KerbalSpaceProgram).

It seems to be contested, but there is a consensus that more antennae increase the communication range of the craft. I believe the phrase *Commnet* is the term for KSP 1.2's new communication network simulation capability.

Comment: Heya, and welcome to Arqade. Sadly, this is not a forum and the answer section is only meant for answers. If you don't find the answers satisfactory, you can ask a new question provided it is different enough from this one, or, once you have more reputation, you can place a bounty on this question in order to have it gain more visibility.

Comment: I fixed this please.

Comment: That's actually great, well done.

Comment: Indeed, related to 1.2 update and above.

The question was asked prior to 1.2.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can determine, there is no decisive advantage in attaching more than one antenna to a craft in the stock (unmodded) game - it will not increase your transmission speed if you have multiple.

However there are a few cases where it may be desirable:

The most expensive antenna (the Communotron 88-88) is an electricity hog; if a latter stage of your rocket has reduced electrical generation or storage capacity (or you are planning for some accidental damage), it may be prudent to stick an additional cheaper antenna to your vessel so you can safely transmit without running out of power in these situations.

Spares in case a planned landing turns out less than ideal and some parts get destroyed on the process.

If your rocket is designed to launch probes, or otherwise detach a section to investigate science while the main craft does other things; each detachable section will need its own antenna, unless you plan to rendezvous and reattach to the main vessel.

You are OCD about symmetry, and for whatever reason it was not possible/practical to place the antenna on the center of your symmetrical axis. Also, I'll roll "Just for aesthetics" under this.

Comment: I fit into the last category. I need 24 Communitrons for the aesthetics... Also actiongroups to extend all at once.

Comment: Extendable antennas are also ones of the cheapest "flip a rover back onto its wheels" elements, so attaching a couple strategically placed ones to your Mun/Minmus rover may be good.

Comment: @SF. huh, Hadn't thought about that. I'll have to keep it in mind for future rover builds (Although I typically prefer sandbox mode, so cost isn't generally an issue for me)

Comment: @TrentHawkins: Purchase price is the least important factor of "cheapness". What matters is weight, form factor when folded, air drag, durability. These are the real costs which matter in sandbox too.

Comment: @Coomie: Same over here. But I noticed after I transmited real data, the antenna that transmitted it, isn't able anymore to anually extend. Did you come over this aswell or is it a local problem of me?

Answer (score 2):

For stock KSP - there is no reason. One antenna is enough to transmit science.

Though there are mods that expand antenna usage, e.g. [RemoteTech](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/83305-1-0-4-RemoteTech-v1-6-8-2015-09-12)
Also another option is to 'just stick-em on' to future proof your crafts for upcoming 1.1 update with enhancements regarding antenna usage, as mentioned in dev notes [here](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/content/350-Development-Relay).

Answer (score 1):

Having more than one antenna allows you to upload more than one science result simultaneously. Your energy use will of course scale accordingly.